# How to draw a line below textview

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Im using single text-view and appending values to it in order to display on constraint layout. I need to separate each textview using a line below it. However, because I'm using append to text-view the line shows up at the end of the list. Is there a way to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LessonActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonStartId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/start"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewLessonId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/lessonresult"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonStartId" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I'm using for loop with this text-view something like this

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
            textViewLessonId.append(user_input+" X "+i+" = "+i*user_input);
            textViewLessonId.append("\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using View:** Add the below `<View.../>` inbetween your `<TextView.../>`

```
<TextView 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="Text 1"/>

<View
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<TextView 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="Text 2"/>
```

**Using LinearLayout:**

```
android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

For Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
 android:showDividers="middle"
 android:orientation="vertical" >            

    <TextView 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Text 1"/>

    <TextView 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Text 2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have single text-view

Comment: @NameetNameet - You mentioned "I need to separate each textview using a line below it" ?

Comment: can you please check again, i have upload my code snippet

Answer (score 1):

1. Use View Tag in Layout xml file to create a line

   ```
    <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
   ```
2. In Java code

   View ruler = new View(myContext); ruler.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
   theParent.addView(ruler,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));

3.If you does not want to use an extra view just for underlines. Add this style on your textView.

```
style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create compound view with **textview** and **view** and use that view instead of plain textview.